# Computer boots, but mouse freezes and keyboard unresponsive

Tags: grub2

I have an HP desktop about 4 years old, 3 gb ram & 500 GB HD. I had Windows 7 on it but messed it up when I tried to dual boot Windows 7 and Elementary OS Linux. I lost Windows 7 and Linux worked ok. I wanted to remove Elementary OS Linux and replace with Ubuntu 14.04. I downloaded the iso file and transferred to a DVD. Checked the DVD and it was on there. I booted from the disk and selected erase hard drive and install Ubuntu by itself. It installed everything and I restarted. Everything booted fine but when I moved the mouse everything froze up including keyboard. Rebooted and same thing. I made a live USB flashdrive and reinstalled Ubuntu and same thing!

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling ubuntu, but an older version, like 12.04 or 13.10. And see if it runs smoothly. Or check if your pc is 32 or 64 bit
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall 12.04. I have found it well supported for drivers and more amenable generally than 14.04. I  a newbie running both. By the way when I first tried to install 14.04 it would only install partially then crash. The download was corrupt so I did a fresh download and reinstall and all was well. You may need to repartition your hard disk as well then reinstall. That was another black hole I fell into.